# Support P2P in Netty or Mina?

Tags: netty, p2p, mina

Hello I am open to a decision, of choosing Netty or Mina for my TCP/UDP server, I am new to both frameworks and wondering if any of them support(s) P2P transformation so some massive data process could be more efficiently processed?

if there is, is there any tutorial or material regarding on this topic of both framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the network level p2p and client-server aren't that different. Someone still has the send the first packet, it's just that usually both sides can accept incoming connections. So networking libraries don't really care about whether you intend to use them for p2p or client-server.

Of course there are some higher-level issues (gossip protocols, distributed data structures, NAT traversal) that are relevant in p2p, but mina or netty do not concern themselves with those.

I.e. mina/netty certainly are useful for networking in general, where *in general* also covers p2p. But they don't really have anything to contribute *specific to* p2p.